# Reuse of macro variables

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I am trying to benchmark a large number of functions, and I have defined macros to generalise the time stamping. I have made a header file benchmarking.h as follows:

```
#include <chrono> 
#include <iostream>

#define START(x) xstart = std::chrono::steady_clock::now()                                         
#define END(x)   xend   = std::chrono::steady_clock::now()                                         
#define TIME(x)  xtime  = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(xend-xstart).count()
#define PRINT(x) std::cout << #x << "(), " << xtime << std::endl
```

This for all macros, x is substituted with the function name, without parameter brackets. e.g `PRINT(foobar);` etc. 
However, I have used the same macros for multiple function names, as I thought that I could substitute x multiple times. 
i.e.

```
START(foobar);
// later...
START(func);
```

However, I get an error:

```
xstart’ has a previous declaration as ‘std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::chrono::duration\<long int, std::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > > xstart
```

It seems like I cannot reuse the variable once I have used it to define a function. 
However, I never get this error with PRINT. So, is it because I am declaring variables?

I am basically trying to come up with a fast way to timestamp functions, so any other suggestions on how to achieve this quickly are welcome.

Comment: Please, explain down vote?

Comment: (Not my vote) Macro's in general are a bad idea. And this particular scheme appears to create names which may collide. Also, you may want to look up `__func__`.

Comment: Yeah, I dont know of a better way to perform this exact task. This allows me to stop collisions (at least among code I defined) as I can create the function name with start/end appended. I'm totally open for better options if you have any; lambdas seem like overkill.

Comment: Oh wow, `__func__`'s the shiznay! Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the macro token concatenation operator `##`:

```
#define START(x) x ## start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now()
```

and similarly for the other macros.

When you just write `xstart`, the `x` is not replaced with the macro argument, but `xstart` is left as is. Argument substitution only operates on single identifiers; they cannot be part of a larger word.

Comment: And this will allow me to "reuse" x?

Comment: When called with `START(func)`, the result will be `funcstart = std::chrono::steady_clock::now()`. `x` is just a placeholder for the argument itself.

Comment: Great! Works, thanks. Not sure if this is preprocessor / compiler specific, but it does not give a valid pre processing token with white space between the macro token concatenation operator and the operands. i.e `x ## start` errors, whilst `x##start` is fine.

Comment: @izaak_pyzaak, That sounds like a compiler bug to me.